# Is there way to run aggenda with mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js, scheduler

I'm working on web app having MySQL DB and Node.js Server.I have to schedule messaging service to send message to different schools at different time intervals. Is there way to run agenda(job scheduler) with MySQL?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/agenda

Comment: No it won't work with any other db than mongo